# Ruby Mechanize getting force_encoding exception

Tags: ruby, mechanize

At least sometimes when I navigate to a page I get this exception

```
undefined method `force_encoding' for #<String:0x898922c>
```

Anyone else seen this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely a 1.8 incompatibility bug in Mechanize:

http://github.com/eric/mechanize/commit/7fd877c60cbb3855652c390c980df1dedfaed820

Answer (score 0):

Yes following the gem hack above it works.